# Stop/Start VM's In a specific Resource Group on Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, automation

Here is the script : as i am totally new to cloud infra automation, i am stuck on this. I am bascially trying to add details gathered of VM's to seperate list depending upon their powerstates.

workflow rg-startstop {

```
param(
    [string]$power,
    [string]$azureResourceGroup
    )
       
    $connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
    try
    {
        # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
        $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         
    
        "Logging in to Azure..."
        Add-AzureRmAccount `
            -ServicePrincipal `
            -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
            -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
            -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
    }
    catch 
    {
        if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
        {
            $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
            throw $ErrorMessage
        } else{
            Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
            throw $_.Exception
        }
    }
    
   
    $vms = Get-AzureRMVM -ResourceGroupName $azureResourceGroup  
    $vmrunninglist = @()
    $vmstoppedlist = @()
    
    
    Foreach($vm in $vms)
        {
            $vmstatus = Get-AzureRMVM -ResourceGroupName $azureResourceGroup -name $vm.name -Status       
            $PowerState = (get-culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase(($vmstatus.statuses)[1].code.split("/")[1])
              
          
            if ($Powerstate -eq 'Running')
            {  
                $vmrunninglist = $vmrunninglist + $vm.name
            }
            if ($Powerstate -eq 'Deallocated')
            {
                $vmstoppedlist = $vmstoppedlist + $vm.name
            } 
        }
    
                
    if ($power -eq 'start') {
       
       foreach ($vm in $vmrunninglist) {
        Start-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $azureResourceGroup -Name $vm.name -Verbose
       }

    }
        
    
    if ($power -eq 'stop') {
        foreach ($vm in $vmstoppedlist) {
            Stop-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $azureResourceGroup -Name $vm.name -Verbose -Force
           }
    }
         
    
}
```

Errors are : you cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
so, please can somebody modify this ?

Comment: [Edit] the question and include the whole error message. It contains information on which part the script failed.

Comment: Check values of `$vm` in `$vms`, `$vmstatus`, `(get-culture)`, `(get-culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase(($vmstatus.statuses)[1]`, `(get-culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase(($vmstatus.statuses)[1].code`, `(get-culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase(($vmstatus.statuses)[1].code.split("/")[1]` by adding try catch. One/few of them is/are null.

Answer (score 0):

Pls check values of `$vm` in `$vms`, `$vmstatus`, `(get-culture)`, `(get-culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase(($vmstatus.statuses)[1]`, `(get-culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase(($vmstatus.statuses)[1].code`, `(get-culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase(($vmstatus.statuses)[1].code.split("/")`[1] by adding try catch. One/few of them is/are null.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the error "`you cannot call a method on a null-valued expression`" is generated if you are trying to do some operation on null valued expression using any method. I believe in this case the expression is `($vmstatus.statuses)[1].code` and the method is `split`.

For testing purpose, If you try to split nonexistent `($vmstatus.statuses)[2].code` then you would see the same null valued expression error as shown below.

[image]

So, to answer your question on how to modify this, please find below updated script that works in my setup.

```
param(
    [string]$power,
    [string]$azureResourceGroup
    )
       
    $connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
    try
    {
        # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
        $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         
    
        "Logging in to Azure..."
        Add-AzureRmAccount `
            -ServicePrincipal `
            -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
            -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
            -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
    }
    catch 
    {
        if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
        {
            $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
            throw $ErrorMessage
        } else{
            Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
            throw $_.Exception
        }
    }
    
   
    $vms = Get-AzureRMVM -ResourceGroupName $azureResourceGroup  
    $vmrunninglist = @()
    $vmstoppedlist = @()
    
    
    Foreach($vm in $vms)
        {
            $vmstatus = Get-AzureRMVM -ResourceGroupName $azureResourceGroup -name $vm.name -Status       
            
            #$PowerState = (get-culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase(($vmstatus.statuses)[1].code.split("/")[1])
            $vmstatusescodes = $vmstatus.Statuses.code
            
            Foreach($vmstatusescode in $vmstatusescodes)
            {
                if($vmstatusescode -eq "PowerState/deallocated")
                {
                    $vmstoppedlist = $vmstoppedlist + $vm.name
                }
                elseif($vmstatusescode -eq "PowerState/running")
                {
                    $vmrunninglist = $vmrunninglist + $vm.name
                }
            }
        }
    
                
    if ($power -eq 'start') {
       
       foreach ($vm in $vmrunninglist) {
        Start-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $azureResourceGroup -Name $vm.name -Verbose
       }

    }
        
    
    if ($power -eq 'stop') {
        foreach ($vm in $vmstoppedlist) {
            Stop-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $azureResourceGroup -Name $vm.name -Verbose -Force
           }
    }
         
    
}
```

The change in the script here is, we have removed the dependency on

1. `$vmstatus.statuses.code` array (as nonexistent 1st array element is the reason for you to see the null valued expression error)
2. [split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-7) method
3. [Get-Culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-culture?view=powershell-7) cmdlet (which is not really required to use in this scenario)

You can always enhance or up-level your script by adding more and more error handling elements i.e., say, at every point of the script you may add a log entry to a separate .log file and also leverage try catch finally blocks to handle the exceptions and log the detailed exception messages to something like an exception file, etc. For more information, check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7) and other about files.

On the other hand, if you are already not aware then see if you can leverage [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management) start stop solution instead of having a custom script.

Lastly, I recommend you to use Az PowerShell instead of AzureRM PowerShell because as instructed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-4.6.1&viewFallbackFrom=azps-4.4.0), starting in December 2018, the Azure PowerShell Az module is in general release and is now the intended PowerShell module for interacting with Azure. So Az modules are latest recommended ones to use and AzureRM modules are the older ones.